# Ambassador metric representing request process time

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus, envoyproxy

I have Ambassador deployed with Istio. StatsD exporter is in place and Grafana dashboard 4698 (https://grafana.com/dashboards/4698).

But it seems there is no metric simply showing the time taken to get a response.

envoy_listener_0_0_0_0_80_downstream_cx_length_ms - has confusing values( with all quantiles)
http_request_duration_microseconds - when converted to milliseconds gives values like 10-20 ms (0.5 - 0.99 quantile) and this is not real either.

Only 2 metrics are working properly:
envoy_cluster_cluster_ext_auth_upstream_rq_time
envoy_cluster_cluster_ext_ratelimit_upstream_rq_time

But these are showing time taken to process request by authentication and ratelimiting services.

How can I get time taken to process whole request? From the moment it hit Ambassador to the moment response was received?